# Filter for last 120 minutes in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to filter a Date/Time column for the latest 120 minutes.

This is not working:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [#"Datum/Tid"] >=Duration.Minutes(DateTime.LocalNow() -(120))
```

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({tab_Silosar, tab_Mjölk, tab_Grädde, tab_Restmjölk, tab_Gränsmjölk, tab_SötGränsmjölk, tab_Permeat, tab_Pastörer, tab_Filråvara, tab_Hydrolys, tab_Syrning}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Tank] <> null)),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"ID", "Streckkod", "Datum", "Tid", "Tank", "Produkt", "Fett", "Protein", "TS", "Laktos", "SNF", "Glukos", "pH", "Nitrat", "Nitrit", "Temp", "Ålder", "Volym", "LoS", "UTS", "Konsistens", "Antibiotika", "Sign", "Kommentar"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"ID", type any}, {"Streckkod", type text}, {"Datum", type date}, {"Tid", type time}, {"Tank", type text}, {"Produkt", type text}, {"Fett", type number}, {"Protein", type number}, {"TS", type number}, {"Laktos", type number}, {"SNF", type number}, {"Glukos", type number}, {"pH", type number}, {"Nitrat", type number}, {"Nitrit", type number}, {"Temp", type number}, {"Ålder", type number}, {"Volym", Int64.Type}, {"LoS", Int64.Type}, {"UTS", Int64.Type}, {"Konsistens", Int64.Type}, {"Antibiotika", type text}, {"Sign", type text}, {"Kommentar", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Datum/Tid", each [Datum]&[Tid]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Datum/Tid", type datetime}}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([#"Datum/Tid"] >= ( DateTime.LocalNow() - #duration(0,1,20,0)) ))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

Comment: What is in Datum/Tid? You need to show some sample data.

Comment: @David It is Date and time. The column is created from a plain date column and a plain time column. See the added picture

Comment: Yes, but your screenshot doesn't show a datetime datatype...

Comment: @David "ABC123" is not the data type? I can change it, maybe I should change it to Date/Time?!

Comment: Yes, that would be a good start. It probably still won't work though. Let me mock something up.

Comment: @David you are right still not working, after changing the datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([#"Datum/Tid"] >= ( DateTime.LocalNow() - #duration(0,1,20,0)) ))
```

This should be the code (you were referring to the wrong previous step):

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({tab_Silosar, tab_Mjölk, tab_Grädde, tab_Restmjölk, tab_Gränsmjölk, tab_SötGränsmjölk, tab_Permeat, tab_Pastörer, tab_Filråvara, tab_Hydrolys, tab_Syrning}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Tank] <> null)),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"ID", "Streckkod", "Datum", "Tid", "Tank", "Produkt", "Fett", "Protein", "TS", "Laktos", "SNF", "Glukos", "pH", "Nitrat", "Nitrit", "Temp", "Ålder", "Volym", "LoS", "UTS", "Konsistens", "Antibiotika", "Sign", "Kommentar"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"ID", type any}, {"Streckkod", type text}, {"Datum", type date}, {"Tid", type time}, {"Tank", type text}, {"Produkt", type text}, {"Fett", type number}, {"Protein", type number}, {"TS", type number}, {"Laktos", type number}, {"SNF", type number}, {"Glukos", type number}, {"pH", type number}, {"Nitrat", type number}, {"Nitrit", type number}, {"Temp", type number}, {"Ålder", type number}, {"Volym", Int64.Type}, {"LoS", Int64.Type}, {"UTS", Int64.Type}, {"Konsistens", Int64.Type}, {"Antibiotika", type text}, {"Sign", type text}, {"Kommentar", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Datum/Tid", each [Datum]&[Tid]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Datum/Tid", type datetime}}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each ([#"Datum/Tid"] >= ( DateTime.LocalNow() - #duration(0,1,20,0)) ))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

Comment: Expression.Error: The field 'Datum/Tid' of the record wasn't found.
Details: "list of all my columns with a single value in it)

Comment: Can you update your post with the full code you have.

Comment: I posted the code. @horseyride no, the text is not in my columns, I just described what I saw, didn't want to type all that stuff.

Comment: Answer updated. You were referring to the incorrect previous step.

Comment: @He David! Thank's a lot! It works. Great code. Greatful!